# Screen resolution guidance to newbie

Tags: html, css

I was provided with an image 1920 x 1080 to use as a background for the main container on the page:

```
<div class="container"></div>
<style>
    .container {
        background: url("background.png");
        width: 1920px;
        height: 1080px;
    }
</style>
```

I'm working with a MacBook with resolution `2880 x 1800`. But the container is way wider and taller than my browser screen. Why my display's screen resolution is bigger than the image and still can't show this `1920 x 1080` image entirely? Is because is retina? What can I do here? I can't scale background with `background-size: contain` because some elements are strictly positioned and they will get misplaced when the browser windows resizes.

Comment: try adding background-repeat:no-repeat;    background-size:cover; and do you have <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> in the <head> section?

Comment: @mlegg Yes. The viewport meta tag is there. I can't use ``cover`` because it resizes the image when the browser window is resized.

Comment: On a Retina screen, a CSS pixel is twice the size of a hardware dot. So your browser thinks you have a 1440×900 screen.

Comment: @MrLister I suspected that. But how can I work around this?

Comment: @Ditto You don't have to. The sane approach is to pretend the screen is 1440 by 900 pixels. For example, a 12px font size is a reasonable font size, small but still readable for most people. At 12 hardware dots it would be too small for comfort. So, you'll have to let go of the idea of addressing each hardware dot. Use pixels.

Answer (score 2):

(Sorry, I don't have the reputation to comment, so I'm answering instead).

If you're `.container` is going to be 1080x1920 no matter what, why not set the background image size to that as well, with a background-position as left top to force it into place?

Whatever your retina display thinks a 'px' unit is, it will match them if they are both set for the background and the container.

```
<div class="container"></div>
<style>
    .container {
        background: url("background.png");
        width: 1920px;
        height: 1080px;
        background-size: 1920px 1080px;
        background-position: top left;
    }
</style>
```

Again, sorry, I'm more curious why this doesn't solve it than recommending an actual solution. I just can't submit comments yet.

Comment: I believe the OP's confusion comes from having to work with a 2dppx screen, which causes a 1920px container to be wider than expected on a 2880×1800 monitor. So it's a matter of adjusting the container to the monitor, not the background image to the container.

Comment: I did that. The img is still wider and taller than the screen.

Comment: I removed the dimensions for the container from the code above. Instead I'm using now ``height: 100%`` after doing the same on ``html, body {}``. Yet, the background img is giant.

Comment: @MrLister How can I do what you say? How can I adjust the container to the monitor so the image is displayed with the size for 1dppx screen? I'm totally lost this this and on top of that I'm frustrated and feeling myself dumb for not understanding why you guys are recommending to do :(

Comment: @Ditto You haven't said what's supposed to happen on a smaller monitor than 1920×1080 pixels.

Comment: @Ditto a good place to start is 1) what you see, 2) what you want to see, 3) any relevant code. Don't give up! You're doing great just by asking. :)

Comment: @MrLister The app, which is a blackjack game, is only supporting devices with screen resolution 1920×1080 pixels and up (is a demo for gambling companies, so they are not trying to display it in phone, tablets, low res computers and so on).

Comment: My concern is that if I manipulate the image because my workstation has display retina, that could affect the view of the game in non-retina display laptops. I won't get hired again by this company to develop their demo games. Some elements like cards and so on has a very specific spot in relation with the background, hence, the background should look the same regardless the device so elements like cards, bets, buttons and so on are not misplaced.

Comment: If the app is designed for 1920×1080 monitors and up, then maybe a Macbook is not the right machine to demo on. You could zoom out the browser to 50%, of course.

Comment: @MrLister Fair enough. But what if the app is being displayed on a retina device when shown to the buyers?

Comment: @MrLister and Clayton: would using a media query for retina devices and declaring the property zoom for the whole document to 50% help in this case without breaking anything? Could that be the way to go? ``@media something { body{zoom: 67%;} }``.

Comment: It's a good hack for the quick demo that you are doing, but I would leave a comment in the css that explains `/* this is a quick hack for retina displays with the demo only, live version will fix this */`

Answer (score 0):

So in lack of a better approach (if there is one) what I'm doing is to zoom the page when it's displayed on retina screen:

```
    .container {
      background: url("background.png") no-repeat;
      width: 1920px;  // the actual width of the background image
      height: 1080px; // the actual height of the background image
    }

    /* for high resolution display */
    @media
    only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
    only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
    only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
    only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
      body {zoom: 67%;}
    }
```

If somebody come up with a better solution, please don't hesitate to post it as an answer and I will unmarked this answer as correct and mark the other one as the correct one.